# chart.js call from javascript button

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have three examples of highcharts:
    
        
        
        MY DOMINE.COM | GRÁFICOS

```
    <!-- add styles -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/miestilo.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <!-- add scripts -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gray.js"></script>
    ***<script src="js/chart1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chart2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chart3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chart....js"></script>***

</head>
```

and I want call them independently using a button javascript

```
<ul>
    <li id='show-a'><a href='javascript:void(0);'>CHART 1</a></li>
    <li id='show-b'><a href='javascript:void(0);'>CHART 2</a></li> 
    <li id='show-c'><a href='javascript:void(0);'>CHART 3</a></li> 
</ul>  

$('#show-a a').live('click',function(){
    firstChart();
    $('#show-a').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);">CHART 1</a>');
});  

$('#show-b a').live('click',function(){
    firstChart();
    $('#show-b').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);">CHART 2</a>');
});

$('#show-c a').live('click',function(){
    firstChart();
    $('#show-c').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);">CHART 3</a>');
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/jlbriggs/TRd7f/

similar to this example

anyone can tell me how I should do?

thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is in `chart1.js chart2.js chart3.js`? And what is the purpose of this `$('#show-a').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);">CHART 1</a>');`? and what does the function `firstChart()` do?

Comment: sorry...... chart1.js chart2..... are charts of highcharts, http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic, and firstChart() would be the call to the charts1 (for example) thanks

Comment: You would like to iniwialize after click or swap only type or somethisn different ?

Comment: charts2.js charts1.js ..... are meteograms, it is one click to load.

Example: now I want chart1.js, click on "Warsaw", now chart4.js, click on "Berlin", now chartx.js, click "Madrid"

Thank you, Sir Bochan